# Who Invented The Number Line?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, terminology, geometry, arithmetic

Recently, I came across [**this article**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915045955/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6623661) and wondered if there really is a definitive answer to the question of who invented the number line?

Comment: Please always include what you're asking in the body of the question, not just in its title.

Comment: Nobody. It was the end result of incremental work of many people which stretched from ancient Greece to 19-th century, see [How were irrational numbers that are not constructible accepted by mathematicians?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3213/55) and [Who gets credit for the real numbers?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3759/55)

Comment: Of related interest: [Pushing Back the Date on the Irrational Number Line](http://pballew.blogspot.com/2009/07/pushing-back-date-on-irrational-number.html) (Pat Ballew's blog, 13 July 2009) and Pat Ballew's [notes on how number lines appeared in old textbooks](http://www.pballew.net/mathbooks#1900).

Comment: Interestingly, just this morning (by accident, and only 2 days after this question was posted), I came across the recently posted online paper [*Descriptions of the Integer Number Line in United States School Mathematics in the 19th Century*](https://www.maa.org/book/export/html/1316210) (see [here](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/descriptions-of-the-integer-number-line-in-united-states-school-mathematics-in-the-19th-century) also) by Nicole M. Wessman-Enzinger in the February 2018 issue of the MAA journal [**Convergence**](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence).

Comment: I don't understand the original question. What does it mean to _invent_ the number line? Are you asking who came up with the idea that numbers can be visualised as lengths, although they don't have the same physical dimension? Or do you mean who invented the real numbers?...

Comment: "*the father of*" Careful, the [PC police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness) might come calling! Actually, this is an example I can sympathize with because, if anything, "mother" seems to me to be the more appropriate term if we have to use either "father" or "mother" and we were to be completely neutral about gender politics.

Comment: In place of the no-longer-valid URL I posted above for "notes on how number lines appeared in old textbooks", search in [this web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180207210716/http://www.pballew.net/mathbooks) for the phrase "number line".

Comment: What is the earliest known ruler, that measures not just integer amounts, but fractions.

Answer (score 6):

Not mentioned in the linked thread is Bombelli, who although not widely published until after cited “candidates” Stevin and Wallis, came before them per Bourbaki’s [historical notes](https://books.google.com/books?id=kTFSfmsjDM0C&pg=PA411) (my emphasis):

> (...) up to the end of the Middle Ages [the] “ratios” of Euclid were customarily described as “numbers”, and the rules for calculating with integers were applied to them without any attempt to analyse the reasons for the success of these methods.
>
> Nevertheless we see **R. Bombelli**, as early as the middle of the 16th century, expounding a point of view on this subject in his *Algebra* [1572] (*), which is essentially correct (provided that the results of Book V of Euclid are assumed to be known); having realized that once the unit of length has been chosen there is a one-to-one correspondence between lengths and ratios of magnitudes, he defines the various algebraic operations *on lengths* (assuming of course that the unit has been fixed) and, **representing numbers by lengths**, obtains the geometrical definition of the field of real numbers (a point of view which is usually credited to Descartes) and thus gives his algebra a solid geometrical foundation (**).
>
> ---
>
> <sub>(*) We are concerned here with Book IV of his *Algebra*, which remained unpublished until modern times; for our purposes it matters little whether or not the ideas of Bombelli on this subject were known to his contemporaries.</sub>
>
> <sub>(**) (...) Bombelli, in the same context, gives with perfect clarity the purely formal definition (such as one would find in modern algebra) not only of negative numbers, but also of complex numbers.</sub>

Comment: I don't really follow how replacing the word "number" by the word "length" solves the problem here.  As far as Euclid and geometry are concerned, it suffices to work with constructible numbers, which are of course not enough.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Which problem do you mean? They say he is in effect defining all numbers geometrically as all lengths. (You may prefer **Barrow**, who they next say “gave a brilliant exposition” of “a point of view which differed little from that of Bombelli”, and “obtain[ed] the field of real numbers in terms which Newton took up again in his Arithmetic, and which his successors up to Dedekind and Cantor did not change”?)

Comment: Leave it to Bourbaki to draw an arbitrary line in the sand along the triumphant march of history from Euclid's Elements to theirs. "*We see R. Bombelli... expounding a point of view on this subject... which is essentially correct*" is priceless. Nevermind that rationals and constructive irrationals admit any number of extensions which all give correspondences between segments and ratios. Only one can be "essentially correct", the one that made it into Bourbaki.

Comment: Right :-) Bombelli identified *his numbers* with the line, or all lengths. I think the question of who (if anyone) started doing that — whether for rationals, constructible numbers, or any extension — is still meaningful.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, thanks for the clarification. Now I understand better what you were trying to say.  I would point out however that the system envisioned by Stevin (namely, unending decimals representing all numbers, whether rational or not) seems to have been the first to enable what is generally considered the ***modern*** number line.

Comment: Some follow-up question to Francois interpretation of the OP's question are: who came up with the idea that quantities of any dimension (say _times_, _masses_, _numbers_ ...) can be visualised not only by lengths but also by _areas_ (e.g. integral), _slopes_ (e.g. derivatives) etc.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody did or several people did. We just don't know whom and its exceedingly unlikely we will ever know. What we can find out is the oldest example of a number line.

I suggest for this the Ishango Bone. Its a baboon fibula with vertical marks ranged in a row representing numbers. Thus the simplest example of a number line. Its been dated to 9,000 BC to 20,000 BC with some arguing for 44,000 BC. The discrepency in aging is due to the nature of volcanic dust that buried the discovery site.

Plus I'd say that the sign for the number one in many cultures from across Eurasia is the straight line. The number line referring to itself. One of the first examples of self-reference and right at the beginning of the story of number!